# Flowbite React Tabs Erroring

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

I've been using Flowbite React without too much of an issue- used various components already, but I've gone to use the Tabs and VS Code says:

```
'Tabs' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type '{ Group: ForwardRefExoticComponent<TabsProps & RefAttributes<TabsRef>>; Item: >FC<TabItemProps>; }' is not a valid JSX element type.
```

I also get a runtime error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Test`.
```

Using latest version of Flowbite React and dependencies:

```
    "node_modules/flowbite-react": {
      "version": "0.6.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/flowbite-react/-/flowbite-react-0.6.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-36mhawQRalOyq40ZLXesCTvcidYBO0vRFb672YSfflQHl5mENzB3o1SW6oGPpedmS/rWTlK+VBK7ia+1UYr+6w==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@floating-ui/react": "^0.24.3",
        "flowbite": "^1.6.6",
        "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
        "react-indiana-drag-scroll": "^2.2.0",
        "tailwind-merge": "^1.13.2"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^18",
        "react-dom": "^18",
        "tailwindcss": "^3"
      }
    },
```

Using vanilla code from: https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/tabs within a tsx file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to 0.7.0-beta.4 and it now works... must be a problem with version 0.6.4

Comment: Thank you for this, I just upgraded the version too and it works.